# Running a program with several parameters using shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, osx

I have a python program that I run it via command line (Mac OSX) as:

`python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations 10`

The file `Experiment.py` should be run multiple times using different `--iterations` values. I do that manually one after another, so when one run is finished, I run the second one with different `--iterations`, and so on. However, I cannot always set near to my laptop to run all of them so I am wondering if there is a way using `shell script` where I can state all runs together and then the shell script executes them one after another (Not parallel, just sequentially as I would have done it by my self)? Something like:

```
python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations 10
python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations 100
python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations 1000
python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations 10000
python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations 100000
```

**Edit:**
What if I have multiple arguments `--X --Y --Z`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
for iteration in 10 100 1000 10000 100000; do
    python -W ignore Experiment.py --iteration "${iteration}"
done
```

If you have multiple parameters, and you want all the various permutations of all parameters, as @Fox noted in a comment below, you can use nested loops.  Suppose, for example, you had a `--name` parameter whose values could be `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`, then you could do:

```
for iteration in 10 100 1000 10000 100000; do
    for name in n1 n2 n3; do
         python -W -ignore Experiment.py --iteration "${iteration}" --name "${name}"
    done
done
```

You could put that in a file, for example `runExperiment.sh` and include this as the first line: `#!/bin/bash`.  You could then run the script using either:

```
bash runExperimen.sh
```

Or, you could make the script executable, then run it:

```
chmod +x runExperiment.sh
./runExperiment.sh
```

If you're interested in some results before others, that'll guide how you structure the loops.  In my example above, the script will run:

```
... --iteration 10 --name n1
... --iteration 10 --name n2
... --iteration 10 --name n3
... --iteration 100 --name n1
```

So it runs all experiments for iteration 10 before moving on to the next iteration.  If instead you wanted all experiments for name `n1` before moving on to the next, you could make the name loop the "outer" loop.

```
for name in ...; do
    for iteration in ...; do
```

Comment: Oh Great! Thank you very very much. What if I have more than one parameters: `--X --Y --Z`, how do I make it ?

Comment: Yes, if you want all permutations of all parameters, the nested loop will do what you're after.

Comment: @AndyDalton Thank you Andy. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel -j1 python -W ignore Experiment.py --iterations {} ::: 10 100 1000 10000 100000
```

Remove `-j1` if you want to run one `Experiment.py` per CPU core in parallel.

To combine with multiple arguments, let us assume you have:

```
-s = S, M, L
--size = small, medium, large
--color =  red, green, blue
```

You want `-s L` to be linked to `--size large` but with all combinations of `--color`:

```
parallel echo s={1} size={2} color={3} ::: S M L :::+ small medium large ::: red green blue
```